# Suppose f is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(a)>0$ for some a.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose f is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(a)>0$ for some a. Then $f(x)>0$ for uncountably many points? I think this statement is true but not quite sure...

Answer (score 4):

It is true because there is a neighborhood $I=[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$ with
$\epsilon>0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in I$. $I$ has uncountably many points.

Comment: Why can you have $f(x)>0$ instead of $f(x) \in V_\delta (f(a))$?

Comment: @annamaw: Because you can choose $\delta = f(a)/2$ and then $f(x) \in V_{\delta}(f(a))$ implies that $f(x) > 0$.